# Multiple threads invoking apache commons io FileUtils.contentEquals() static method in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading

What will happen if multiple threads invoke the `apache` `commons io` `FileUtils.contentEquals()` static method in parallel?

Here can we guarantee the end result of each execution without any race conditions as this method contains only local variables?

Please advice on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method invokes IOUtils.contentEquals, and I think, there's nothing to make race condition in multithreaded environment.

`FileUtils.contentEquals()`

```
public static boolean contentEquals(File file1, File file2) throws IOException {
    boolean file1Exists = file1.exists();
    if (file1Exists != file2.exists()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!file1Exists) {
        // two not existing files are equal
        return true;
    }

    if (file1.isDirectory() || file2.isDirectory()) {
        // don't want to compare directory contents
        throw new IOException("Can't compare directories, only files");
    }

    if (file1.length() != file2.length()) {
        // lengths differ, cannot be equal
        return false;
    }

    if (file1.getCanonicalFile().equals(file2.getCanonicalFile())) {
        // same file
        return true;
    }

    InputStream input1 = null;
    InputStream input2 = null;
    try {
        input1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
        input2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
        return IOUtils.contentEquals(input1, input2);

    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(input1);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(input2);
    }
}
```

---

`IOUtils.contentEquals()`

```
public static boolean contentEquals(InputStream input1, InputStream input2)
        throws IOException {
    if (!(input1 instanceof BufferedInputStream)) {
        input1 = new BufferedInputStream(input1);
    }
    if (!(input2 instanceof BufferedInputStream)) {
        input2 = new BufferedInputStream(input2);
    }

    int ch = input1.read();
    while (EOF != ch) {
        int ch2 = input2.read();
        if (ch != ch2) {
            return false;
        }
        ch = input1.read();
    }

    int ch2 = input2.read();
    return ch2 == EOF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the source code of FileUtils.contentEquals, it uses a BufferedInputStream to make the comparison between the two files (by giving an InputStream of the two files to IOUtils.contentEquals).

And since BufferedInputStream is supposed to be thread-safe (it is what I read at least, I never try it myself), I suppose that FileUtils.contentEquals should be thread-safe as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your **multiple threads are passing the same parameters or different parameters.** Multiple threads with different parameters should be thread safe because there are no resources in contention.

If you are passing the same parameters via multiple threads, I would first question the need to do this. But ignoring that, it should be fine since the method creates independent input streams. The only possible thing to go wrong in this case is if the OS complains about multiple access to the same file.